# enable vi command line editing from .perldb rc afterinit in perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, vi, rc

Whenever I start the perl debugger from a script with a -d option, the session starts with emacs command line editing.  I then type ESC ctrl J to enable vi editing.  I want to enable vi from the get-go.

I tried using the following .perldb:

```
&parse_options("HistFile=.perlDebugHist");
 sub afterinit { push @DB::typeahead, ("o inhibit_exit", chr(27).chr(10)) }
```

but when the session starts, it says

```
auto(-2)  DB<62> o inhibit_exit
        inhibit_exit = '1'
auto(-1)  DB<63> 

Unrecognized character \x1B; marked by <-- HERE after :db_stop;
<-- HERE near column 96 at (eval 9)[/usr/share/perl/5.22/perl5db.pl:737] line 2.
 at (eval 9)[/usr/share/perl/5.22/perl5db.pl:737] line 2.
    eval 'no strict; ($@, $!, $^E, $,, $/, $\\, $^W) = @DB::saved;package main; $^D = $^D | $DB::db_stop;
;
' called at /usr/share/perl/5.22/perl5db.pl line 737
    DB::eval called at /usr/share/perl/5.22/perl5db.pl line 3110
    DB::DB called at ~/bin/debug.pl line 61
```

Comment: You can change environment variable specifying [default editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615178/getting-the-default-text-editor-used-in-system) to `vi` -- see documentation for your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround that assumes you use the gnu readline library:

Create a file called `perldb_inputrc` in the current directory with content:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Then change the `afterinit()` sub to:

```
sub afterinit {
  if (!$DB::term) {
    DB::setterm();
  }
  $DB::term->read_init_file('perldb_inputrc');
  push @DB::typeahead, "o inhibit_exit";
}
```

See [perldoc perl5db](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5db) for more information.

**Update**:

A simpler approach is to the [readline init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html). You can use a global file `~/.inputrc` or a use a local one for the current debugging session only by setting the environment variable `INPUTRC`. For example, using the above `perldb_inputrc` file as an example, you could use (in your `.perldb` init file):

```
sub afterinit { push @DB::typeahead, "o inhibit_exit" }
```

and then run the Perl script like this:

```
INPUTRC=./perldb_inputrc perl -d myscript.pl
```

Comment: Thanks but no go: Unknown method `read_init_file' in Term::ReadLine::Perl at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 121.  libreadline6 libreadline6-dev already installed.

Comment: Have you installed [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu) ? If you are using the system perl you can use the package manager to install it. For example on ubuntu, the package is called [libterm-readline-gnu-perl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libterm-readline-gnu-perl)

Comment: I found a simpler approach, see my updated answer.

Comment: Your original modification of afterinit{} works once I installed Term::ReadLine::Gnu.   Much appreciated!  It's been driving me nuts for years.